# Speeding up the non-negativity algorithm for multilinear function with interval probabilities?

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, recursion, probability-or-statistics

The algorithm is a branch-and-bound algorithm that calculates the non-negativity of a multilinear function with interval probabilities. The lines 9-11 has an optimization that is explained on the 10-14 lines of Table 1 in publication [here](http://sal.aalto.fi/publications/pdf-files/ptop13.pdf).

> **what kind of methods would you use to speed up this kind of recursive algorithm?**

**Algorithm**

```
Algo[f0_, lb0_, ub0_] := 
  Module[{f = f0, lb = lb0, ub = ub0, monomials, fp, fm, bvar, blb, 
    bub}, If[f == 0 || f == 0.0, Return[True]];
   monomials = f // MonomialList;
   fp = Select[monomials*1.0*D, (First[#] >= 0) &] /. {D -> 1};
   fm = Select[monomials*1.0*D, (First[#] < 0) &] /. {D -> 1};
   If[Plus @@ (fp /. lb) + Plus @@ (fm /. ub) >= 0, Return[True]];
   If[Plus @@ (fp /. ub) + Plus @@ (fm /. lb) < 0, Return[False]];
   bvar = Variables[f] // First;
   blb = Select[lb, ((# // First) == bvar) &];
   bub = Select[ub, ((# // First) == bvar) &];
   Algo[(f /. blb), lb, ub] \[And] Algo[(f /. bub), lb, ub]];
```

**Simple example: non-negativity check for $p_1+p_2-p_1p_2$ with bounds $p_i\in[0.01,0.04]$**

```
Algo[Subscript[p, 1] + Subscript[p, 2] - Subscript[p, 1] Subscript[p, 2], 
 Table[Subscript[p, i] -> 0.01, {i, 7}], Table[Subscript[p, i] -> 0.04, {i, 7}]]
```

Comment: It would help if you give some example where the function is noticably slow (perhaps a larger one than the one you gave).

Comment: Any answers to this one? I cannot open bounty here because no reputation here. I shared this question to my colleques in Twitter.

Comment: Between explanation and example, I still have no idea what it is this algorithm is intended to do.

Comment: Voted to close your own question? Strange remark; you could have deleted it any time you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for your precious comments, I added applied references (not just pure mathematical investigation) and explained the simple demo and made it simpler. You only need to understand multilinearity and non-negativity to understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my thesis **"Implementation of an algorithm for verifying the non-negativity of a multilinear function in a hypercube"** about this [here](http://sal.aalto.fi/publications/pdf-files/tlos14.pdf) (password is "sal" and username "sal"). The key algorithm is not specified in the publication, focusing only on the key implementation idea with the hypercubes -- this was a requirement by my instructor.

**Shortly**

I showed that the nature of data (nature of the multilinear function) is an important decision variable in choosing the optimization! This is a fascinating concept -- it basically mean: you need to specify your multilinear function more specifically: whatever method you choose it needs to be specific, I like graph-theoretical/polytopical way of characterising the multilinear functions because then you are simply considering polytopical problems. You transform the earlier messy multilinear problem into a new domain where you can use their tools making it easy to deal with.

**Optimization on the Lines 9-11**

This optimization strategy (invented by my instructor) is not optimal with all kind of data. I showed this in my thesis by finding cases where they did not work, multilinear functions in Table 4 on the page 20. The way I found the multilinear functions is not specified and is an intriguing research topic because MLFs have many applications over different industries.

[image]

You can find more about the research [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/17158/5902), not hard stuff or let say you need to be very careful :)